# Selecting suppliers that have at least the same approval codes as the contract requires

Tags: sql, db2, relational-division

Have a table of suppliers that have 'approval codes' (VNDAPP)  and a table of contracts that have 'requirement codes' (COXA).  Contracts can have any number of requirements and suppliers can have any number of approvals.

```
VNDAPP: (vendor approvals table)
VNUM    (vendor number)
REQMT   (approval code)

COXA:   (contract requirements table)
CONTR   (contract number)
REQMT   (requirement)
```

Need to find all suppliers that have approvals that, as a minimum, meet the requirements of a certain contract.

Example contract 7736 has requirements number 1 and 10.  There are 27 suppliers that have both of these as a minimum.  Since the requirements are variable, I cannot hard code them into the query.  I'm not certain this qualifies as a  relational division problem...

```
SELECT VNDNO
FROM VNDAPP
LEFT JOIN COXA ON VNDAPP.REQMT = COXA.REQMT
GROUP BY VNDAPP.VNDNO
HAVING Count(COXA.REQMT) = (SELECT count(*)
FROM COXA WHERE COXA.CONTR = '7736'
GROUP BY COXA.CONTR)
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!

Example data:

```
Contract Requirement (COXA):
CONTR   REQMT
7736    1
7736    10
7737    1
7737    4
7737    6
7738    5
7739    1



Supplier Approval (VNDAPP):
VNDNO   REQMT
10019   1
10020   1
10020   2
10020   10
10021   1
10021   4
10021   5
10021   6



Desired result:
CONTR   VNDNO
7736    10020
7737    10021
7738    10021
7739    10019
7739    10020
7739    10021
```

Comment: At least show us table schema and some sample data. Where is store those number 1 to 10 Where are the requirement and where are those approvals

Comment: Which table is which? What columns do they have?

Comment: edited to show description of COXA and VNDAPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that you have two binding tables `supplier_approval(supplierid, approvalid)` and `contracts_requirement(contractid, requirementid)`, where `approvalid` and `requirementid` corresponds. Then you can use the following query

```
select sa.supplierid
from supplier_approval sa
where sa.approvalid IN (
    select cr.requirementid
    from contracts_requirement cr
    where cr.contractid = 7736
 )
group by sa.supplierid
having count(distinct sa.approvalid) = (
    select count(*)
    from contracts_requirement cr
    where cr.contractid = 7736
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Radim - only is missing one vendor.

Comment: Let me help you. What is interesting about the missing vendor?

Comment: Oddly enough, the original query did return them.

Comment: My mistake...I had made an error when counting the approvals manually.  Radim, your solution is correct.

Comment: Much thanks, @Radim!Taking this an additional step, if I needed to display all suppliers that are approved for every contract's minimum requirements, what mods would I need to make?  How would I join the contracts_requirement table?

Comment: what are contract minimum requirements? I thought that all contract requirements are in `select cr.requirementid from contracts_requirement cr where cr.contractid = 7736`

Comment: Yes, that's for one specific contract (#7736).

Comment: You mean that you have some `Supplier(supplierid, other_atributes)` table and you are not sure how to add it into the query, right?

Comment: Actually, I only need the two tables in your answer above (supplierid and  contracts_requirement).  I would like to have every contract and requirement in the contracts_requirement table and show all corresponding suppliers.

Comment: I do not get it. You have list of supplier ids matching the contract requirements. I believe that some sample data and expected result would help. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: Original question has been edited to include example data and desired result.

Comment: So you would like to see the matched vendor numbers for each contract, ok? Not only  7736, but for every contract, right?

Comment: Exactly.  Sorry I wasn't explaining myself thoroughly.

Comment: I believe that you should post it as a new question, best

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want:

```
SELECT VNDNO
FROM VNDAPP JOIN
     COXA
     ON VNDAPP.REQMT = COXA.REQMT
WHERE COXA.CONTR = '7736'
GROUP BY VNDAPP.VNDNO
HAVING Count(*) = (SELECT count(*)
                   FROM COXA
                   WHERE COXA.CONTR = '7736'
                  );
```

That is, count the requirements on the vendor that match the requirements for the contract.  Then, check if the total count matches the total for the contract.

This assumes you don't have duplicate requirements on either side.