# Select suppliers for each contract that have all codes required by the contract

Tags: sql, db2, relational-division

I have a table of contracts that have "requirement codes" (COXA) and a table of suppliers that have "approval codes" (VNDAPP). Contracts can have any number of requirements and suppliers can have any number of approvals.

Example data:

```
Contract Requirement (COXA):
CONTR   REQMT
7736    1
7736    10
7737    1
7737    4
7737    6
7738    5
7739    1

Supplier Approval (VNDAPP):
VNDNO   REQMT
10019   1
10020   1
10020   2
10020   10
10021   1
10021   4
10021   5
10021   6

Desired Result:
CONTR   VNDNO
7736    10020
7737    10021
7738    10021
7739    10019
7739    10020
7739    10021
```

[In another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859081/selecting-suppliers-that-have-at-least-the-same-approval-codes-as-the-contract-r/53859176?noredirect=1#comment94626360_53859176) I have received a response that works when I specify the contract number in the query:

```
select sa.supplierid
from supplier_approval sa
    where sa.approvalid IN (
    select cr.requirementid
    from contracts_requirement cr
    where cr.contractid = 7736
 )
group by sa.supplierid
having count(distinct sa.approvalid) = (
    select count(*)
    from contracts_requirement cr
    where cr.contractid = 7736
)
```

The problem is I need to have matching suppliers for every contract number.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CROSS JOIN to generate tuples of (contracts, suppliers, contract requirement), then use LEFT JOIN to match contract requirements with supplier approvals:

```
SELECT
    contract_requirement.contr,
    suppliers.vndno,
    COUNT(contract_requirement.reqmt) AS req_count,
    COUNT(supplier_approval.reqmt) AS app_count
FROM contract_requirement
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT vndno
    FROM supplier_approval
) AS suppliers
LEFT JOIN supplier_approval ON suppliers.vndno = supplier_approval.vndno AND contract_requirement.reqmt = supplier_approval.reqmt
GROUP BY contract_requirement.contr, suppliers.vndno
HAVING COUNT(contract_requirement.reqmt) = COUNT(supplier_approval.reqmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join` and `group by` and then `having` to be sure that you have all requirements:

```
select cr.contr
from (select cr.*, count(*) over (partition by cr.contr) as cnt
      from contract_requirement cr 
     ) cr join
     supplier_approval sa
     on sa.approvalid = cr.requirementid
group by cr.contr, cr.cnt
having cr.cnt = count(*)
```

Comment: Access Client Solutions doesn't like the "(" character before "partition".

Comment: @user3593083 . . . That is the syntax for window functions, which DB2 supports.